# Silverlight and Opera

Tags: opera, silverlight, opera-10

I am an avid fan of Opera, and have been for a number of years. Despite its bad rap, it is a very solidly built browser that has phenomenal standards support.

A some of the sites that I use have started moving from Flash (or custom plugins) to Silverlight. One of the most notable is NetFlix Instant Watch. In some cases, Silverlight works perfectly in Opera. However, in cases such as with Netflix Instant Watch, opera has some trouble loading Silverlight.

I believe this is simply because of how the Silverlight plugin is configured. With past versions (Silverlight 2, mostly with Silverlight 3) some clever User javascript would solve the problem in Opera. However, I have not been able to get Silverlight 4 to work in most cases, and there are still issues with Silverlight 3.

Does anyone know how to get the Microsoft Silverlight plugins working smoothly in Opera? I am not afraid of user javascript, addons, or other tweaks. I would love to get Silverlight working consistently and smoothly across the board in Opera.

Comment: Opera has a bad rap?

Comment: @random: Let me put it this way: Opera is very misunderstood and mistreated by the greater development community, considered a cheap and broken browser that does not support the standards, regardless of its stellar standards support. It is used by tens of millions of people, but has very little, if any, support from major companies like Microsoft.

Comment: Well, for one, Opera supports many IE-specific features (IE-specific in the sense that it doesn't run in FF, Safari, or Chrome).

Comment: It also fully and strictly supports the open standards, quite unlike IE. ;)

Comment: Is this still an issue?

Comment: @random: If you use the new Opera (v15 and up) it uses Chromium for the rendering engine. Seems to work with Silverlight now...however the new Operas have had basically all the amazing features that made it a worthwhile browser stripped from it. At the moment (and God only knows for now long into the future) Opera is basically a Chrome clone. It has lost it's strict standards adherence as well, which was actually one of the features I liked. So, yes, it supports Silverlight, but at a cost.

Comment: Tried 15, but am sticking with version 12 until it becomes untenable. And then it's back to Firefox unless Opera comes back to the Opera it used to be. But that comment was mostly wondering if you want to keep the question around still.